Using "it" to refer to "amounts of"

This is really huge amounts of money, but it is much less than we need. ( It appears on a workbook. I'm not sure if it's from a reliable source)

Questions:

Is there a grammatical error in this sentence? Especially the plural after "this is"
To refer to "amounts of money," is it right to use "it"? The explanation I can think of is that the speaker regards this plural thing as a whole concept.  Am I right?


To your second question: I can imagine different examples where it would be more natural for "the speaker to regard the plural things as a whole concept," like maybe "Take a cup of flour, a half cup of water, and an egg, and mix it all together." Here "it" is understood as "all that stuff." In your "money" example, I would argue that the "it" is reasonable, but it's not really necessary. Maybe the bigger problem is that a plural "amounts" wasn't necessary, at least without context. Maybe it would make sense if the preceding sentences had listed several individual amounts.


This is really huge amounts of money, but it is much less than we need. ( It appears on a workbook. I'm not sure if it's from a reliable source)

I find this an inappropriate example for learning material because of the mismatch of number; however, even educated native speakers do occasionally speak this way for effect.
To my ear, in this case, the word "is" is not the simple copula but is a loose equivalent of "represents."  The sentence probably is a very informal equivalent of "This quantity represents really huge amounts of money."
The lack of number agreement is probably jarring for most speakers but does occur in a certain style of speech associated with less favored members of society and is sometimes copied for effect.  For instance, to express surprise I might say: "This is really big bucks" as an equivalent of "This is really a huge amount of money."
I would be less likely to say "This is really huge amounts of money" because it sounds like an inappropriate mix of loose and precise speech and the result of mixing up two different sentences that don't work so well together.
Such loose speech or writing would be strongly stigmatized in serious speech or writing, except for comic effect, and would be unacceptable in school work outside of a creative writing class.  Many careful speakers might never use some of these expressions.

The mismatch of 'number' (singular/plural) needs correcting
Either:
These are really huge amounts of money, but they are much less than we need.
'They' is a plural pronoun referring to some things previously mentioned (large amounts of money). Possible example: Our restaurant took £500 on Monday, £650 on Tuesday, and £500 on Wednesday (but we needed £1000 each night to stay in business).
Or:
This is a really huge amount of money, but it is much less than we need.
'It' is a singular pronoun referring to a thing previously mentioned (a large amount of money). Possible example: We have £50,000 in the bank. Our restaurant needs a new roof and wiring job which will cost £60,000.

A related question came to mind about "lots". " This is lots of money but it's less than what we need"-  is this the one thing to say?  I'm a little confused here because I was taught that generally, "lots of money" should be treated as singular,

@ForOU Please ask about separate questions separately. "Lots" and "amounts" are different words and work in different ways. Meanwhile: would argue that it could be reasonable for casual use to use "it" in the second half of your sentence, with an understood antecedent of "the money"; we might do this in other contexts where something can be seen both as a group and as a whole. It wouldn't be OK, even for casual use, though, to say "this is… amounts."
